# How to properly use Ruby CGI module for gzipped output?

Tags: ruby, encoding, cgi, gzip, deflate

This code doesn't work in Firefox 38.0.1 (Content Encoding Error) and Google Chrome 42.0.2311.152 (ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED), however it works with Opera 12.16 and cURL (with --compressed option):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "cgi"
require "zlib"

cgi=CGI.new(:accept_charset => "UTF-8")

#header
puts "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"" 
puts "Content-Encoding: gzip"
puts

#generating some html output

output=""
output << "<html><body><style> p {line-height:20%;font-size:9px;font-family:monospace} a {text-decoration:none} a[title]:hover:after {font-size:9px;font-family:monospace}</style>"
output << "<p style='text-align:center'>#{Time.now}</p>"
output << "<p>#{"-"*190}</p>"
output<<"</body></html>"

z = Zlib::Deflate.new(9)
compressed = z.deflate(output,Zlib::FINISH)
z.close
puts compressed
```

This code works in all browser, and cURL too:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "cgi"
require "zlib"

cgi=CGI.new(:accept_charset => "UTF-8")

puts "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"" 
puts "Content-Encoding: gzip"
puts

output=""
output << "<html><body><style> p {line-height:20%;font-size:9px;font-family:monospace} a {text-decoration:none} a[title]:hover:after {font-size:9px;font-family:monospace}</style>"
output << "<p style='text-align:center'>#{Time.now}</p>"
output << "<p>#{"-"*190}</p>"
output<<"</body></html>"

File.write("gzip.temp",output)
compressed=IO.popen("cat gzip.temp|gzip -c","r").read
puts compressed
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, problem solved, one have to use this code section:

```
z = Zlib::Deflate.new(9,16+Zlib::MAX_WBITS)
compressed = z.deflate(output,Zlib::FINISH)
z.close
puts compressed
```